# Missing data points after full_join()

Tags: r, join, missing-data

I'm joining two large dfs where the groups are different, and the columns are almost identical, meaning that are some sort of dublicates of many columns, but they each have columns that are not in the other df. Those points should of course be NA in the total df.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orQqw.png): This is the result of full_join(df1, df2, by=c("Sample Description", "Group")). I know there is data for C0, C2, C3 etc. for the rows 32-71.

How do I get those data included in the total df?

I think it only takes for x(df1) or y(df2), but is unable two take data from both and join/combine/add those to the total df.

```
#Joining FIA+LC dfs for both 20+130-, and 50-60/70-80 day old mice into two dfs

df1 <- full_join(FIA, LC)
df2 <- full_join(FIA1, LC1)
```

This i succeeded with as the groups are identical within FIA and LC, and FIA1 and LC1

Then I did full_join of df1 and 2:

```
df3 <- full_join(df1,df2, by=c("Sample Description", "Group"))
df3
```

Here i succeeded with join the rows by Sample Description and Group of df1 and df2, but it does not take the data with that matches the column e.g. C0, which it also names C0.x.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is your problem/you are trying to achieve. Can you add a small example data set to your question to illustrate your problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have added i picture of the problem, however i find it difficult to explain better than i have here

Comment: I don't know how, maybe someone have an explanation, but this code worked: dplyr::bind_rows and this time i used raw data and not pre processed data.